# A set theory problem - proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that $X \cap (\bigcup_{i \in I} Y_i) = \bigcap_{i \in I} (Y_i \cap X) $

Is the indices finite? How do I know it isn't $1 \leq i < \infty$?

Also, isn't the RHS just $Y_1 \cap Y_2 \cap ....\cap X$? (assuming we have finite intersection).

**EDIT**

A quick counterexample from myself disproves this.

$Y_1 = \{1,2 \}$ and $Y_2 = \{ 2\}$ and $X = \{1\}$

**EDIT2**

Yes, yes, yes; thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Also, you want the right hand side to have a small $\cup$, not a small $\cap$.

Comment: The two sides are in general decidedly not equal.

Comment: @sidht: I assume you *meant* to write
$$\textstyle X \cap (\bigcup_{i \in I} Y_i) = \bigcup_{i \in I} (Y_i \cap X),$$
the second big symbol being a $\bigcup$ instead of a $\bigcap$?

Comment: No this was how the problem was posed.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, no. That's why I am confused

Comment: sidht: you cannot prove the LHS = RHS, as currently stated, because in general, it is **not true**. You can prove what Zev posted (see "possible duplicate" comment above).

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Of course it is not a duplicate! This one has intersection on the right, making the statement in general false. The question linked to has union on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexing set needn't be finite. Maybe it should read $$X\cap \bigcup Y_i=\bigcup (X\cap Y_i)\text{ ? }$$ You can argue as follows:

First suppose $x\in X\cap\bigcup Y_i$. Then $x\in X$ and $x\in\bigcup Y_i$. Thus $x\in X$ and $x\in Y_i\;$ for at least one $i$, say it is $j$. Thus, $x\in X\cap Y_j$. This means $x\in \bigcup (X\cap Y_i)$.

Can you do the other direction?

Comment: Thank you but you changed the problem.

Comment: @sidht Did you read what the others pointed out? The problem is wrong as stated.

Comment: I know, that's why I disproved it. I gave you $+1$ for the correction.

Comment: let $x \in \bigcup (X \cap Y_i) \implies x \in X \cap Y_i$ for some $i \iff x \in X$ and $x \in Y_i$. But $Y_i \subset \bigcup Y_i$. This gives the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

No, the index set $I$ could be anything, even uncountably infinite. The problem didn't say anything about $I$ being finite, so you can't assume it.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the right-hand side is the intersection you indicate in the post. And the two sides are in general not equal. So proving equality will be a challenge!

For example, let $Y_1$ be the set of odd numbers and $Y_2$ the set of even numbers. Let $X=\{1,2\}$. The right-hand side is empty, the left is not, it is equal to $X$.

As to whether $I$ is allowed to be infinite, that is context-dependent. In principle there is no restriction, but in a very finite-oriented course, there might be an implicit convention that index sets are finite.

**Remark:** If we replace the outer intersection on the right by union, the modified equation becomes true, whatever the size of the index set. A straightforward proof can be given by element-chasing.

Comment: *So proving equality will be a challenge* exactly.